# template methods in normal source code?

Tags: scala

In Scala, you can do things like passing in a function variable as parameter etc. but I wonder if there can be more template like functionality?

In this simple example (doesn't compile, just a skeleton of what i want to have), the wrapper function contains some code which is almost exactly the same, but only with one line that's different. Suppose the wrapper is a long skeleton which I don't want to write twice, can I just pass in either `sub1` or `sub2`? Notice these two functions have different signatures this make it not fit for curried solution:

```
object MyTemplate{

  def sub1(a: Int): String={
    a.toString
  }

  def sub2(b: String, c: String): Int={
    return b.toInt*x
  }

  def wrapper(i: Int)(f: ???): Double ={
    if (xxxx)
        do something
     else 
         do something else 
         [this line needs to call either sub1() or sub2() ] 

     common code continues
  } 
}
```

Comment: What's the supposed criteria to obtain the parameters needed for the "dynamic method" call? Would you accept to pass them as a further argument to `wrapper`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I am confident that with type parameters, function composition, currying, etc. you can find a way to do what you want. Without more specifics in your question, it's hard provide a more specific answer though.